# Graphics problem on 11.10 install and use: black screen, weird resolution, pointer flickers

Tags: 11.10, installation, intel-graphics, display, pointers

I really can't find anything that can solve my problem. Here it is:

I tried to install 11.10 32bits on my Dell Studio Hybrid from CD, but I would directly get a blank screen and my screen would turn off. So I found on the Internet the "Nomodeset" solution (shift, then F6) that let me install the OS.

After installing, of course, same problem after the first purple screen: just black, screen turns off. I used Grub again to use the safe mode, chose in the menu "resume to boot normally" and it went fine, I could use my desktop and do the updates, but problems remain:

- I can't boot without using the safe mode;
- My pointer flickers every time I go over a button or something;
- And my display is stretched and ugly (can't fix it in "display").

I really can't use Ubuntu like this. Could anyone at least explain to me what the problem is, and maybe help me to have a usable computer?

For info, the only proprietary driver available is for my bluetooth card, and this is my configuration:

Processor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T6400 @ 2.00GHz × 2

Graphics: VESA : Intel(r)GM965/PM965/GL960 Graphics

2.9 Gio memory

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable `nomodeset` for your system installation now that you have completed the install from live CD.

Follow the steps in the answer by coldfish in [How to set nomodeset for installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation) to make the changes permanent.